How do I disable any kind of automatic conversion into excel when using xlwings?
When using xlwings, I want to, for example, write the string "4 / 5" into excel. However, if I write.
sheet[0,0].value = "4 / 5"

I get: string converted to date
I do not want to write a date. I want to write "4 / 5". Any way to fix this?
I tried looking for different format options or such, but was unable to find any.

Have you tried .options(numbers=str) ?

You might find this helpful https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html

Just write it as text sheet[0,0].value = "'4 / 5".   That is, place a single quote as the first character.

@temoadeishvili Tried that, same result.

@moken This worked, sort of. Though I would prefer not to have "'" written in excel. Any way to circumvent this?

You cannot disable this action, it's how Excel works.
To have the value show as entered basically needs the cell to be set as text or formatted as a fraction.
Any of the following would work;
import xlwings as xw


file = 'foo.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(file)
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    ### Set the cell format before writting the value to the cell
    ### Set cell format to TEXT
    ws['A1'].number_format = "@"
    ws['A1'].value = '4/5'
    ### Set the cell format to a fraction. This results in a numeric value
    ws['A2'].number_format = "# ?/?"
    ws['A2'].value = '4/5'

    ### Use TEXT formula to set cell value to TEXT format as fraction
    ws['A3'].formula = "=TEXT(4/5,\"# ?/?\")"

    ### Use Space, Single Quote or 0 prefix to set value to TEXT
    ws['A4'].value = " 4/5"
    ws['A5'].value = "'4/5"
    ws['A6'].value = "0 4/5"  # This results in a numeric value

    wb.save(file)



